# Compojure App Stopped Working Suddenly in Production

Tags: java, clojure, compojure, ring

Something strange happened last week and cost me major face with my peers.  I haven't had time to figure out the root cause, but now I'm digging in.  Last week on Thursday night, after a month or so of uptime, almost all instances of a web service I wrote with Compojure went down at the same time, 5 days before a product launch that depends on it.  Imagine.

Clojure, which was already viewed suspiciously for being "fringe" was immediately blamed, and as you might imagine this has caused a lot of changes.  Burn.  I rewrote my service in Java and got it ready but QA says no go.  What a nightmare.  Now I have a few minutes and I am really wondering if the community can help.

Onto the failure.  Here is a stack trace that came with the surprise 500 errors:

```
2013-09-26 18:00:55.934:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1525259451-38221: Error for /path/to/api
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clout/core$re_groups_STAR_$iter_242246$fn247$fn_248
at clout.core$re_groups_STAR_$iter_242246$fn_247.invoke(core.clj:23)
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:60)
at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:484)
at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
at clojure.core$map$fn__4207.invoke(core.clj:2479)
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:60)
at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:484)
at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
at clojure.core$map$fn__4211.invoke(core.clj:2490)
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:60)
at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:484)
at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133)
at clojure.core.protocols$seq_reduce.invoke(protocols.clj:30)
at clojure.core.protocols$fn__6026.invoke(protocols.clj:54)
at clojure.core.protocols$fn_5979$G5974_5992.invoke(protocols.clj:13)
at clojure.core$reduce.invoke(core.clj:6177)
at clout.core$assoc_keys_with_groups.invoke(core.clj:54)
at clout.core.CompiledRoute.route_matches(core.clj:84)
at compojure.core$if_route$fn__515.invoke(core.clj:38)
at compojure.core$if_method$fn__508.invoke(core.clj:24)
```

Prod eng said: "After cycling the app things just work."

What could cause something like this?  Someone else said, "it looks like it losing its class files" but to my knowledge I don't know what that means or how how that might happen...  In the clout core, the lines that threw the exception look like

```
(defn re-groups*
  "More consistant re-groups that always returns a vector of groups, even if there is only one group."
  [^Matcher matcher]
  (for [i (range (.groupCount matcher))]
      (.group matcher (int (inc i)))))
```

So what is going on?  A bug? Subterfuge?  Has anyone had a Compojure app up for more than a few months without cycling?

Comment: Can you add your Java, Clojure, and Lein versions to the question?

Comment: `[compojure "1.1.5"], [lein-ring "0.8.7"]`

Comment: My clojure problems in long running apps with class loading (no matter what class) are always because of insufficient permgen size. Clojure uses lots of static strings and classes (more than idiomatic java), so it needs larger permgen.

Comment: `almost all instances of a web service I wrote with Compojure went down at the same time` were they running in the same machine?

Comment: Hi vemv, no, they were not.  They were in different environments, QA, Prod, etc.  @noisesmith, thats interesting, thanks for the heads up.  Ill have to look at that some more.

Comment: Can you run the output from "lein deps-tree" to the question? I think you might know where I am going with this....